# Split multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL with 2 fields ID (int) and RawData (varchar(max))

The raw data field contains pipe delimited data

> AB|1223445|01012017|abc|........

There are 75 fields in the records and there are upto 1 million rows.

I need to parse out this data and place it in another table with 75 fields. the data contains dates, ints, varchars (max is varchar(70)), numeric(5,2) and money field/data types.

Currently I am using a function to split the string and then pivoting the returned data and inserting it into the table. but this is taking 4 hours.

Is there a quicker way of doing this?

I am using SQL 2014

If I haven't given enough info please ask me any questions you have.

thanks

FYI

Function being used to split each record

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
    ) 
    RETURNS @output TABLE(ID int, splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    ) 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @start INT, @end INT, @Count INT
        set @Count = 1
        SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
        WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
            IF @end = 0  
                SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (ID, splitdata)  
        VALUES(@Count, SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)
        Set @Count = @Count+1
    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

PIVOT being used per record

```
 While @CountRec > 0
    BEGIN
        Select top(1) @RawData = RawData from @RawDataTable     

        Insert into RawData_Parsed(01, 02, 03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
        21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,
        41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,
        61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75)
        select  [1],[2],[3],substring([4],5,4) +'/'+ substring([4],3,2) +'/'+ substring([4],1,2),[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],
            case when len([14]) = 0 then NULL else substring([14],5,4) +'/'+ substring([14],3,2) +'/'+ substring([14],1,2) end,
            case when len([15]) = 0 then NULL else substring([15],5,4) +'/'+ substring([15],3,2) +'/'+ substring([15],1,2) end,
            case when len([16]) = 0 then NULL else substring([16],5,4) +'/'+ substring([16],3,2) +'/'+ substring([16],1,2) end,
            case when len([17]) = 0 then NULL else substring([17],5,4) +'/'+ substring([17],3,2) +'/'+ substring([17],1,2) end,
            case when len([18]) = 0 then NULL else substring([18],5,4) +'/'+ substring([18],3,2) +'/'+ substring([18],1,2) end,
            [19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],
            case when len([32]) = 0 then NULL else substring([32],5,4) +'/'+ substring([32],3,2) +'/'+ substring([32],1,2) end,
            case when len([33]) = 0 then NULL else substring([33],5,4) +'/'+ substring([33],3,2) +'/'+ substring([33],1,2) end,
            [34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],
            case when len([42]) = 0 then NULL else substring([42],5,4) +'/'+ substring([42],3,2) +'/'+ substring([42],1,2) end,
            case when len([43]) = 0 then NULL else substring([43],5,4) +'/'+ substring([43],3,2) +'/'+ substring([43],1,2) end,
            [44],
            case when len([45]) = 0 then NULL else [45] end,
            [46],[47],
            case when len([48]) = 0 then NULL else substring([48],5,4) +'/'+ substring([48],3,2) +'/'+ substring([48],1,2) end,
            case when len([49]) = 0 then NULL else substring([49],5,4) +'/'+ substring([49],3,2) +'/'+ substring([49],1,2) end,
            [50],
            case when len([51]) = 0 then NULL else [51] end,
            [52],[53],
            case when len([54]) = 0 then NULL else substring([54],5,4) +'/'+ substring([54],3,2) +'/'+ substring([54],1,2) end,
            case when len([55]) = 0 then NULL else substring([55],5,4) +'/'+ substring([55],3,2) +'/'+ substring([55],1,2) end,
            [56],
            case when len([57]) = 0 then NULL else [57] end,
            [58],[59],
            case when len([60]) = 0 then NULL else substring([60],5,4) +'/'+ substring([60],3,2) +'/'+ substring([60],1,2) end,
            case when len([61]) = 0 then NULL else substring([61],5,4) +'/'+ substring([61],3,2) +'/'+ substring([61],1,2) end,
            [62],
            case when len([63]) = 0 then NULL else [63] end,
            [64],[65],
            case when len([66]) = 0 then NULL else substring([66],5,4) +'/'+ substring([66],3,2) +'/'+ substring([66],1,2) end,
            case when len([67]) = 0 then NULL else substring([67],5,4) +'/'+ substring([67],3,2) +'/'+ substring([67],1,2) end,
            [68],
            case when len([69]) = 0 then NULL else [69] end,
            [70],[71],
            case when len([72]) = 0 then NULL else substring([72],5,4) +'/'+ substring([72],3,2) +'/'+ substring([72],1,2) end,
            case when len([73]) = 0 then NULL else substring([73],5,4) +'/'+ substring([73],3,2) +'/'+ substring([73],1,2) end,
            [74],
            case when len([75]) = 0 then NULL else [75] end,
            @JobTaskID
        from 
        (
            select ID,splitData from dbo.fn_splitstring(@RawData, '|')
        ) src
        pivot
        (
            MAX(splitData) for Id in ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24],[25]
                    ,[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[37],[38],[39],[40],[41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48]
                    ,[49],[50],[51],[52],[53],[54],[55],[56],[57],[58],[59],[60],[61],[62],[63],[64],[65],[66],[67],[68],[69],[70],[71]
                    ,[72],[73],[74],[75])
        ) piv;

        delete top(1) from @RawDataTable
        set @CountRec = @CountRec - 1
        set @RawData = null

    end
```

Comment: Forget about suboptimal split functions. Export src table to file and import to target table with BULK.

Comment: @lad2025 never thought of that, thanks

Comment: add some sample data & desired result which could help to resolve your issue.

Comment: @YogeshSharma the desired result is to get the data split and into the correct format quickly. It's only slightly quicker to split the fields as varchars so I think the data is almost irrelevant. The issue is the methods I'm using to split the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI

I followed lad2025's suggestion to export the data to text files and imported it that way using SSIS.

So the SSIS package I created extracts the data and exports it to a txt file that then reloads it as a pipe delimited text file with the relevant number of columns.

I then carry out all required processing on the data.

The way I initially imported the data was taking 4+ hours its now running in less than 10 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You can generate dynamic sql texts and execute it.

```
While @CountRec > 0
BEGIN
    Select top(1) @RawData = RawData from @RawDataTable     

    DECLARE @SqlText NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @SqlText = 'INSERT INTO RawData_Parsed VALUES (''' + REPLACE (@RawData,'|',''',''') + ''')'

    EXEC (@SqlText)

    delete top(1) from @RawDataTable
    set @CountRec = @CountRec - 1
    set @RawData = null

END
```

After insertion completed you can update data for formatting.

```
UPDATE RawData_Parsed
SET
    [4]= case when len([4]) = 0 then NULL else substring([4],5,4) +'/'+ substring([4],3,2) +'/'+ substring([4],1,2) end,
    [14] = case when len([14]) = 0 then NULL else substring([14],5,4) +'/'+ substring([14],3,2) +'/'+ substring([14],1,2) end,
    [15] = case when len([15]) = 0 then NULL else substring([15],5,4) +'/'+ substring([15],3,2) +'/'+ substring([15],1,2) end,
    [16] = case when len([16]) = 0 then NULL else substring([16],5,4) +'/'+ substring([16],3,2) +'/'+ substring([16],1,2) end,
    [17] = case when len([17]) = 0 then NULL else substring([17],5,4) +'/'+ substring([17],3,2) +'/'+ substring([17],1,2) end,
    [18] = case when len([18]) = 0 then NULL else substring([18],5,4) +'/'+ substring([18],3,2) +'/'+ substring([18],1,2) end,
    [32] = case when len([32]) = 0 then NULL else substring([32],5,4) +'/'+ substring([32],3,2) +'/'+ substring([32],1,2) end,
    [33] = case when len([33]) = 0 then NULL else substring([33],5,4) +'/'+ substring([33],3,2) +'/'+ substring([33],1,2) end,
    [42] = case when len([42]) = 0 then NULL else substring([42],5,4) +'/'+ substring([42],3,2) +'/'+ substring([42],1,2) end,
    [43] = case when len([43]) = 0 then NULL else substring([43],5,4) +'/'+ substring([43],3,2) +'/'+ substring([43],1,2) end,
    [45] = case when len([45]) = 0 then NULL else [45] end,
    [48] = case when len([48]) = 0 then NULL else substring([48],5,4) +'/'+ substring([48],3,2) +'/'+ substring([48],1,2) end,
    [49] = case when len([49]) = 0 then NULL else substring([49],5,4) +'/'+ substring([49],3,2) +'/'+ substring([49],1,2) end,
    [51] = case when len([51]) = 0 then NULL else [51] end,
    [54] = case when len([54]) = 0 then NULL else substring([54],5,4) +'/'+ substring([54],3,2) +'/'+ substring([54],1,2) end,
    [55] = case when len([55]) = 0 then NULL else substring([55],5,4) +'/'+ substring([55],3,2) +'/'+ substring([55],1,2) end,
    [57] = case when len([57]) = 0 then NULL else [57] end,
    [60] = case when len([60]) = 0 then NULL else substring([60],5,4) +'/'+ substring([60],3,2) +'/'+ substring([60],1,2) end,
    [61] = case when len([61]) = 0 then NULL else substring([61],5,4) +'/'+ substring([61],3,2) +'/'+ substring([61],1,2) end,
    [63] = case when len([63]) = 0 then NULL else [63] end,
    [66] = case when len([66]) = 0 then NULL else substring([66],5,4) +'/'+ substring([66],3,2) +'/'+ substring([66],1,2) end,
    [67] = case when len([67]) = 0 then NULL else substring([67],5,4) +'/'+ substring([67],3,2) +'/'+ substring([67],1,2) end,
    [69] = case when len([69]) = 0 then NULL else [69] end,
    [72] = case when len([72]) = 0 then NULL else substring([72],5,4) +'/'+ substring([72],3,2) +'/'+ substring([72],1,2) end,
    [73] = case when len([73]) = 0 then NULL else substring([73],5,4) +'/'+ substring([73],3,2) +'/'+ substring([73],1,2) end,
    [75] = case when len([75]) = 0 then NULL else [75] end
```

Comment: wouldn't that would require the creation of a new table with 75 fields that are all varchars parsing the data into that and then inserting the data into the final table - as the correct data type. Would that speed it up?

Comment: using a temp table that have all varchar columns, and select and insert from that table probably works faster.

Comment: are temp tables not slower than physical tables?

Comment: actually there are no difference between temp and permanent tables. Slow and fast depends on indexes on the tables